# Add error message to @Html.ValidationSummary

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using standard MVC3 Razor views with unobtrusive Javascript validation, using `@Html.ValidationSummary` to show them at the top of the form. If the standard validations (things like `[Required]`) pass, I then run some very custom client-side validation that fires when the user hits the Submit button. (The validation looks across a number of form elements to make sure that the proper set of them have been checked, etc., so it's not as simple as just creating a new custom validator for a single field).

I'd like the possible error(s) I construct there to be shown in the `ValidationSummary` list, but I can't figure out how to get the error message to appear there.

Comment: In client-side or server-side?

Answer (score 45):

**In client-side:**

```
function YourCustomValidator() {
    // do your validation logic here via JavaScript
    return true; // or false based on your validation logic
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    // take your own form-selector like ("form", this)
    $("form", this).first().submit(function () {
        return (YourCustomValidator() && $(this).valid());
    });
});
```

**OR In server-side:**

Think you have a model like this:

```
public class Test {
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

and when you are validating it:

```
if(ModelState.IsValid) { // default validations run here
    if(/* some custom validations run here, there is an error about "FullName" */){
        // you should set the "key" for Model-Error to "FullName"
        ModelState.AddModelError("FullName","error-message goes here")
    }
    if(/* some custom validations run here, the error is global, not on "FullName" */){
        // you should set the "key" for Model-Error to an empty-string
        ModelState.AddModelError("","error-message goes here")
    }
    // also you can test for model-errors again like this:
    if(ModelState.IsValid) { // if you add any error above, this will be "false"

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm looking for just client-side in this case. My question is if I DO find an error in "YourCustomValidator", how do I get my specific error message to appear? I already have server-side validation, which allows me to set any error message I want via "AddModelError", but I want to do the equivalent in Javascript.

Comment: You can create a custom logic to show an error-message via JS and/or you can create custom validation-attribute class via C#. which one do you mean?

Comment: I don't know why this has 32 votes, it does not answer the question at all.

Answer (score 6):

You can do so just adding the `Error Message` to the `ModelState` should display the error message for you, provided that you have `ValidationSummary()` called on your view.

To add the error to the `ModelState` just do this:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("ColumnNameOrErrorMessageKeyInState","error message goes here")
```