# How to not display ASP MVC ValidationSummary in case when errors already displayed field by field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would not like to display the ValidationSummary in case it only displays already displayed field related errors. However I do need ValidationSummary when custom server side validation error occurs like:

```
if (!UserManager.IsEmailConfirmed(user.Id))
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "You need to confirm your email.");
    return View(model);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`

Comment: @Stephen I initially thought this would've been answered before. Couldn't find a dupe though. Do you know of any?

Comment: @CodeCaster I think I answered an almost identical question before - just can't find it yet

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`@Html.ValidationSummary(excludePropertyErrors: true)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee839469(v=vs.118).aspx).

This overload, when `excludePropertyErrors` is `true`, hides property errors like your *"The Email field is not a valid e-mail address."* and *"The Password field is required."* from the validation summary. See also [@Html.ValidationSummary(true) - What's the true do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635406/html-validationsummarytrue-whats-the-true-do).

It *doesn't* detect whether you print those though `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`, so if you forget any of those, you can get failing form submissions that don't tell you why they fail.

To manually add *non*-property validation errors, call `ModelState.AddModelError("", "Custom error")` (note the empty string) as explained in [Add error message to @Html.ValidationSummary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882008/add-error-message-to-html-validationsummary) and [ASP.NET MVC Html.ValidationSummary(true) does not display model errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818219/asp-net-mvc-html-validationsummarytrue-does-not-display-model-errors).

Comment: Perfect answer! Even answered a follow-up question that usually arises :)

Answer (score 0):

like @CodeCaster say Simple add

> @Html.ValidationSummary(true).

If the bool parameter is true then only model-level errors are displayed. If the parameter is false then all errors are shown. [reference](http://www.ciiycode.com/06i6NgxjQXPj/htmlvalidationsummarytrue-whats-the-true-do)