# Show only server side errors in validation summary

Tags: validation, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, modelstate, validationsummary

I have the following view:

```
@model MyProject.Models.RegisterViewModel

<div class="content">
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>E-Bill Saver Registration</h2>
    <hr />

    <div class="columns top-gap">
        <div class="first cell width-6 dark-blue-headings">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @*@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
                <div class="form-horizontal">                        
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("Account Number", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 bold" })
                        <br />@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccountNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AccountNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input" } })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("MPNumber", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 bold" })
                        <br />@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MPNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MPRN, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input" } })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("Email Address", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 bold" })
                        <br />@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input" } })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("Confirm Email Address", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 bold" })
                        <br />@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input" } })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("Password", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 bold" })
                        <br />@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input" } })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("Confirm Password", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 bold" })
                        <br />@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input" } })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="submit" value="Register" class="opc_button" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>       
</div>
```

If there are validation errors on any of the fields then the error message is displayed below the label as expected and wanted. On my controller however I have some custom logic errors and I am adding them to the modelstate as follows:

```
else
                {
                    //This email address is already assigned to a user      
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Email Address : ", "Error! You must enter an email address that is unique to your account.");
                    return View(model);
                }
```

If I uncomment the validationsummary on my page then it will display the custom server side error but it will also display the single validation errors which I want underneath the labels. Is there any way that I can set the validation summary to ignore the values that are being listed individually and only return server side validation errors?

Comment: Use `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to not display ASP MVC ValidationSummary in case when errors already displayed field by field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847308/how-to-not-display-asp-mvc-validationsummary-in-case-when-errors-already-display)

Comment: They share the same dictionary, so no, not out-of-the-box. You would need to replace the ValidationSummary with a custom one.

Answer (score 1):

The first string parameter of `ModelState.AddModelError` method is the key later used to bind the message to the model property.
If you want to display that error message next to email label, make first parameter of `AddModelError` match your property name:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Error! Email already used...");
```